# Change month name to date in python

Tags: python

I am trying to change month name to date in python but i m getting an error:

```
ValueError: time data 'October' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

My CSV has values such as October in it which I want to change it to 10/01/2018

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

f = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
keep_col = ['Month']
new_f = f[keep_col]
f['Month'] = f['Month'].apply(lambda v: datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%m/%d/%Y'))
    new_f.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just write a function mapping to each? In fact, a dictionary will do.

```
def convert_monthname(monthname):
    table = {"January": datetime.datetime(month=1, day=1, year=2018),
             "February": datetime.datetime(month=2, day=1, year=2018),
             ...}

    return table.get(monthname, monthname)

f['Month'] = f['Month'].apply(convert_monthname)
```

Answer (score 5):

As an elaboration of the answer by @AdamSmith, a better way to define a mapping between names and dates is to use the `calendar` module that already has a list of names:

```
import calendar
table = {name: datetime.datetime(month=1, day=val, year=2018) 
          for val, name in enumerate(calendar.month_name) if val>0}
```

Comment: Upvoting for simplicity, great answer! There's a good tutorial [here](https://www.guru99.com/calendar-in-python.html) on other things you can do with the calendar module.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of passing a format string like `%m/%d/%y` to `strftime` is that you're specifying what format the input strings are going to be in.

You can see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), but it's pretty obvious that a format like `%m/%d/%y` is not going to handle strings like `'October'`. You're asking for a (zero-padded) month number, a slash, a (zero-padded) day number, a slash, and a (zero-padded) (two-digit) years.

If you specify a format that actually *does* match your input, everything works without error:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('October', '%B')
datetime.datetime(1900, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

However, that still isn't what you want, because the default year is 1900, not 2018. So, you either need to [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) that, or pull the month out and build a new datetime object.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('October', '%B').replace(year=2018)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

Also, notice that all of the strings that `strptime` knows about are locale-specific. If you've set an English-speaking locale, like `en_US.UTF-8`, or `C`, then `%B` means the English months, so everything is great. But if you've set, say, `br_PT.UTF-8`, then you're asking it to match the Brazilian Portuguese month names, like `Outubro` instead of `October`.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Since I don't actually know Brazilian Portuguese, that was a pretty dumb example for me to pick… but Google says it's Outubro, and when Google Translate did so ever lead wrong one?</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the data is mostly in the format you have specified (`mm/dd/yyyy`) but some outlier rows have month names in them.

Without adding any extra dependencies:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%m/%d/Y'
MONTH_NAME_MAP = {
    "january": 1,
    "jan": 1,
    "february": 2,
    "feb": 2,
    # ...
}

def parse_month_value(value):
    # check if the value is a name of a month
    month_int = MONTH_NAME_MAP.get(value.lower())
    if month_int:
        this_year = datetime.date.today().year
        return datetime.datetime(month=month_int, day=1, year=this_year)

    # try to parse it normally, failing and raising exception if needed.
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, DATE_FORMAT)
```

---

then

```
f['Month'] = f['Month'].apply(parse_month_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @DYZ actually did it for me, I added the strftime to create the dict as the date string I wanted

```
months = {str(name).lower(): datetime.datetime(month=val, day=1, year=2016).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
      for val, name in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if val>0}
```